# How to setup a controller's routes when it doesn't match the name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

I want to have the url `/community` so here is what I did. I created the controller: `CommunitiesController` and have this in my routes:

```
get 'community' => 'communities#index'
```

Did I set this up incorrectly? The problem I'm having is I now want to add the kaminari pagination gym but the naming mismatch is causing this not to work:

```
  get 'community' => 'communities#index'
  resources :communities do
    get 'page/:page', action: :index, on: :collection
  end
```

as it wants me to user `/communities/page/1` when I want to use `/community/page/1`

What would be the correct way to setup a controller and route with this use case?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
get 'community' => 'communities#index'
get 'community/page/:page' => 'communities#index'
```

But you may need to tweak `paginate` method and pass explicit params to make it work. I am not sure if this will be required, but it looks something like this

```
<%= paginate(@communities, params: { controller: 'communities', action: 'index' } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The more "resourceful" way of declaring your original `community` route is as follows:

```
resources :communities, path: "community", only: "index"
```

Then you can add the Kaminari route according like this:

```
resources :communities, path: "community", only: "index" do
  get "page/:page", action: :index, on: :collection
end
```

For further explanation, read the very helpful [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide.